# What does Fertile Essence mean for a female Mokolé?

Tags: world-of-darkness, werewolf-the-apocalypse

As I was researching the [Zhong Lung/Same-Bito connection](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/129678/what-happens-to-shapeshifters-born-to-a-diferent-species-of-animal), I came across a Zhong Lung Flaw that only appeared in the Breed Book 6 - Mokolé:

> Fertile Essence (1 point Flaw)
>
> You are filled with life-giving Essence, to the peril of anyone who knows you. If anyone drinks from the same glass as you, uses the same bathing pool, or even handles your clothing or utensils, they can have children who resemble *you*. Even people who are sterile or barren might become pregnant because of you (Storyteller's opinion, and certainly not applicable to metis characters). This can become annoying, and cause serious misunderstandings.<sup>Breed Book 6  Mokolé p76</sup>

As it is worded, it seems to imply that the bearer of the flaw is *male*, spreading his genetic code by touching people. But what is the implication for a *female* Zhong Lung with this trait? Will she suddenly be the (spiritual?)*father* of children of other people?

I have not been able to track down this flaw in any other edition, so it might be endemic to this one rulebook because of it being... game breaking. I mean, it certainly IS game breaking when the Dragon King takes a bath in the cistern for Shanghai and ends up starting a Baby Boom...

Answer (score 5):

**Nowhere in the flaw is it stated that you have to be male.**

There is no reason for the effect to be male only.

You can say that a female with this flaw simply makes people pregnant with copies 
 of her genetic code.

Comment: Why would it have to be copies? Two XX chromosome parents can produce an XX child that’s not a clone and that’s genetically related to both XX parents.

Comment: ¨they can have children who resemble you.¨ i took this as the reason for her copying her genetic code.  A person with this flaw will create people that look very similar to herself. So if one parent was a different race their children will still look like the person with this flaw.

Comment: I think that’s misunderstanding the flaw, but that explains that part of the answer. Thanks!

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you think i am missunderstanding? i will change my answer if you can explain.

Comment: The wording seems to be the usual reference to how a child resembles its parents, especially when such resemblance reveals an *unexpected* parent. It’s not saying “looks identical”, just resembles, like normal children conceived normally do.